# How to get a single line flushleft in the eqnarray environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, environments, arrays

I would like to get a single line in the eqnarray environment flushed left.
This is my code so far

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta_{j}      & = & \sum_{i = j+1}^{d} n_{i}  \\
and \nonumber\\
g^{\prime}(x)   & = &  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
    \cos (n_{p-1} \, \theta_{1})            &  \text{for~~} n_{p} = 0   \\
    \sin ( (n_{p-1} + 1) \, \theta_{1})     &  \text{for~~} n_{p} = 1   \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}
```

I would like to make the line with the the `and \nonumber\\` flush left.

Here is a picture of the current output along with a description of what I would like to happen

[image]

I have tried using combinations of `\hspace`, `\hfill` and `\noindent`  without success. The reason for typing the code in this manner is because I really want to keep the equal signs aligned.

Comment: do not use `eqnarray` use `align` then you can use `\intertext{and}`

Comment: See the answers to the posting [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) for a thorough list or reasons why one shouldn't use `eqnarray`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `eqnarray` as it gives bad spacing around the alignment points. Use one of the `amsmath` environments,  `align` or `alignat`, which furthermore are simpler to type, and `\intertext`. Here, I loaded `mathtools`, an extension of amsmath, for its `\shortintertext` command (better vertical spacing for a single word). Also I replaced the `\left\{\begin{array}{ll} ... \end{array}` with the simple `cases*` environment, which switches the second column in text mode. Note that you don't have to type `g^{\prime}` for the derivative: a simple `g'` will do:

```
\documentclass {book}

\usepackage {mathtools}

\begin {document}

\begin{align}
\delta_{j} & = \smashoperator{\sum_{i = j+1}^{d}} n_{i} \\
\shortintertext{and}
g'(x) & = \begin{cases*}
\cos (n_{p-1} \, \theta_{1}) & for $n_{p} = 0$, \\
\sin ( (n_{p-1} + 1) \, \theta_{1}) & for $n_{p} = 1$. \\
\end{cases*}
\end{align}

\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right (as usual…). I'll even use the `cases*` environment,, which sets the second column in text mode.